# On event doesn't work

Tags: jquery

A simple question:

When I use

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-del-top', function(e) {})
```

everyhing work, but if I use

```
$('.btn-del-top').on('click', function(e) {})
```

nothing work.Is there some explanation?

Comment: Don't put tags in your question title. **Do** put code in code blocks.

Comment: There can be dozens of explanations... where is your code? Do you have your code inside `$(document).ready();` ? Is .btn-del-top loaded after the DOM has finished?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: Read next topic http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/direct-vs-delegated-events-with-jquery-on-method.html?m=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it could be because `btn-del-top` elements are created dynamically or are created after the `$('.btn-del-top').on('click', function(e) {})` code is executed.

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5rf78/1/): In this case it is not working because the code is not inside dom ready

Comment: @Momo1987 no... only one of the formats of `on()` is a replacement of `live()` that is the one working

Comment: Ah ok thanx for the information, so for dynamically created element iI need to use $(document).on('click', '.btn-del-top', function(e) {}) ,right?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason would be that when you run the second code snippet, the elements don't exist yet, so they aren't found, and so they aren't hooked up. The first code snippet doesn't look for them until it sees a click on `document` (e.g., probably much later).

The *reason* they aren't found may vary:

1. If your code looking for them is in a script tag *above* where they're defined in the HTML, they won't exist yet. For instance:

   ```
   <!-- Won't work, the element doesn't exist when you look for it -->
   <script>
   $('.btn-del-top').on('click', function(e) {})
   </script>
   <span class="btn-del-top">...</span>
   ```

   But:

   ```
   <!-- Will work, the element exists when you look for it -->
   <span class="btn-del-top">...</span>
   <script>
   $('.btn-del-top').on('click', function(e) {})
   </script>
   ```

   And:

   ```
   <!-- Will work also work, jQuery will call your code later when
        all elements in the markup have been created -->
   <script>
   $(function() { // shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)`
       $('.btn-del-top').on('click', function(e) {})
   });
   </script>
   <span class="btn-del-top">...</span>
   ```
2. If you create them *later* using code, they won't exist earlier when you try to hook them up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding .btn-del-top dynamically, the second one binds before that element exists, thus it doesn't bind.